# Diagrama de Classes X Diagrama de Entidade-Relacionamento

Tags: java, diagrama-de-classes, der

Estou emperrado no empasse POO X Banco de Dados Relacional. Para melhor fundamentar as minhas indagações segue, em primeiramente algumas modelagens (simplificadas) que fiz:

1 - Diagrama de Classes

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma programação possível para esse diagrama:

1.1 - Classe Item

```
public class Item{

    private int codigoItem;
    private String descricaoItem;

    public void setCodigoItem(int codigoItem){
        this.codigoItem = codigoItem;
    }

    public int getCodigoItem(){
        return codigoItem;
    }

    public void setDescricaoitem(String descricaoItem){
        this.descricaoItem = descricaoItem;
    }

    public String getCodigoItem(){
        return codigoItem;
    }
}
```

1.2 Classe Pedido

```
public class Pedido{

    private int codigoPedido;
    private List<Item> itens = new ArrayList<>();
    private float quantidade;
    private BigDecimal valorPedido;

    public void setCodigoPedido(int codigoPedido){
        this.codigoPedido = codigoPedido;
    }

    public int getCodigoPedido(){
        return codigoPedido;
    }

    public void setItens(Item itens){
        this.itens.add(itens);
    }

    public List<Item> getItens(){
        return itens;
    }
}
```

1.3 - Classe Romaneio

```
public class Romaneio implements Requisicao{
    private int codigoRomaneio;
    private List<Pedido> pedidos = new ArrayList<>();
    private BigDecimal valorRomaneio = BigDecimal.ZERO;

    public void setCodigoRomaneio(int codigoRomaneio){
        this.codigoRomaneio = codigoRomaneio;
    }

    public int getCodigoRomaneio(){
        return codigoRomaneio;
    }

    @Override
    public void criarPedido(Pedido pedido){
        this.pedidos.add(pedido);
    }

    public List<Pedido> getPedidos(){
        return pedidos;
    }

    public void setValorRomaneio(BigDecimal valorRomaneio){
        this.valorRomaneio += valorRomaneio;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValorRomaneio(){
        return codigoRomaneio;
    }
}
```

1.4 Inteface Requisicao

```
public interface Requisicao{
    public void criarPedido(Pedido pedido);
}
```

O problema surge (supondo que a codificação esteja correta) quando vai se modelar o banco de dados:

2 - Modelo Conceitual

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3 - Modelo Lógico

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por um lado, no diagrama de classes, deve-se indicar nos objetos `Pedido` uma lista de objetos `Item` e uma lista de objetos `Pedido` na classe `Romaneio`. Por outro lado, pela modelagem conceitual e lógica, mais especificamente no caso do relacionamento Romaneio-Pedido, é a tabela `Pedido` (que parte no diagrama de classes) que recebe informações de `Romaneio` (FK). Então estou tendo dificuldades de codificar isso. Tenho que passar os romaneios para os pedidos (banco de dados), mas a classe Pedidos não tem campo do tipo romaneio, mas justamente o contrário, já que `Romaneio` tem uma lista de pedidos.
Alguém já se deparou com essa questão? Como resolver(ram)?

4 - View (retornos e métodos de salvamento)

```
private Item retornarItem(){
    bean.Item item = new bean.Item();

    item.setCodigoItem(codigoItem);
    item.setDescricaoItem(txtDescricao.getText());

    return item;
}

private Pedido retornarPedido(){
    bean.Pedido pedido = new bean.Pedido();

    pedido.setCodigoPedido(codigoPedido);
    pedido.setItem(retornarItem());
    pedido.setQuantidade(Float.parseFloat(txtQuantidade.getText()));
    pedido.setValorPedido(new BigDecimal(txtValorTotal.getText()));
    pedido.setRomaneio(?) // e aqui?
}

private Romaneio retornarRomaneio(){
    bean.Romaneio romaneio = new bean.Romaneio();

    romaneio.setCodigoRomaneio(codigoRomaneio);
    romaneio.setPedido(retonarPedido()); //???
    romaneio.setValorRomaneio(valorPedidoAtual());
}

private boolean salvarPedido(){
        try{
            codigoPedido = dao.Pedido.inserir(retornarPedido());
            return dao.Transacao.completar();

        }catch(SQLException sqle){
            System.out.println("Impossível salvar o pedido. ERRO: " 
                    + sqle.getMessage());

            return false;
        }
}

private boolean salvarRomaneio(){
        try{
            codigoRomaneio = dao.Romaneio.inserir(retornarRomaneio());
            return dao.Transacao.completar();

        }catch(SQLException sqle){
            System.out.println("Impossível salvar o romaneio. ERRO: " 
                    + sqle.getMessage());

            return false;
        }
}
```

5 - DAO (esqueleto)

```
public class Item {
    public static int[] inserir(bean.Item item) throws SQLException{

    }
}

public class Pedido {
    public static int[] inserir(bean.Pedido pedido) throws SQLException{

    }
}

public class Romaneio {
    public static int inserir(bean.Romaneio Romaneio) throws SQLException{

    }
}
```

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Cara, sua ideia está certa, o DB vai partir do Romaneio e depois ir pro Pedidos, o Pedidos só tem que ter esse FK para poder se localizar e dizer de quem ele é "filho", mas não que sua classe tenha que ter essa informação...

Como mencionado no comentário abaixo, você utiliza uma DAO para o CRUD, o meio mais facil (ao meu ver) é criar uma função na classe RomaneioDAO que insira no DB todas as informações pertinentes ao mesmo, isso vai deixar a função bem grande eu sei, mas evita de fechar a conexão e fazer a reabertura do mesmo mil e quinhentas vezes.
Segue um exemplo de como poderia ser:

```java
//la na classe RomaneioDAO
public boolean inserirRomaneioCompleto(Romaneio romaneio){
    sql = "INSERT INTO romaneio (id...) VALUES (...);
    try{
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.... todos os inserts;
        stmt.execute();
        sql = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @id"; //esse comando vai pegar o id inserido no romaneio
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.execute();
        //no sql abaixo passa o id que voce pegou ali em cima, que é o FK
        //é só no local onde vai ir o FK você colocar o @id
        sql =  "INSERT INTO pedido (id,...,cod_romaneio) VALUES (....,@id)"
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.execute();
        //e assim sucessivamente ate completar seu insert total..
        //desse modo você não precisa fechar a conexão mil vezes...
    }finally{
    //aqui você fecha a conexão...
    }
}
```

Comment: mas como eu faço para passar o Romaneio para o método salvar? No meu caso eu uso um método para isso e esse método retorna Um Item para salvar Item, um Pedido para salvar um Pedido e um Romaneio para salvar um Romaneio. Nesse caso, a classe Pedido deveria ter um atributo Romaneio, já que no banco 'pede' o romaneio como FK. Como eu traria essa informação?

Comment: Voce esta utilizando qual tipo de banco de dados? Usa metodos DAO?

Comment: Isso, um DAO para cada classe.

Comment: Adicionei mais informações.

Answer (score 1):

**Silva**, a questão levantada depende da sua estratégia de persistência dos dados.

Se você está persistido seus dados na "unha" usando as classes do **namespace** **java.sql** e escrevendo manualmente os comando **DML** para manipular essas informações no banco de dados, não necessariamente você precisa ter o atributo que representa a **FK** da tabela **Romaneio** na sua classe de **Pedido**. Você pode por exemplo em um momento no seu código ter um método **salvarPedido** que receba uma instancia do **Romaneio** com os pedidos já adicionados a ela, colocar um **foreach** para cada pedido nessa instância do **Romaneio** com isso você conseguiria montar seu **"insert"** concatenando as informações necessárias para salvar o pedido e teria o **ID** do **Romaneio**.

No caso de estar usando um **framework ORM** para persistência de dados como o **Hibernate**, o próprio já te obriga a usar uma estratégia diferente, a sua classe Pedido teria o atributo que representa a **FK** da tabela **Romaneio**, pois, o **Framework** precisa dessa representação entre **OBJETO X BANCO DE DADOS** então, o que ocorre normalmente cada uma de sua classe vai ter um atributo que representa cada coluna da tabela que ele está associada.
No caso da classe **Pedido**, teria o atributo representando a **FK**, pois é uma coluna na tabela.

Comment: É na "unha" @Bruno Eles usando DAO.

Comment: Adicionei mais informações.